# Chrome is not able to work when I click Enter button

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, jquery, events, browser-compatibility

If enter key is pressed and then search button clicked event is called. My chrome doesn't work . IE is OK . How do I fix ? Thanks in advance

```
$('#txtSearch').keypress(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==13)
  $('#btnSearch').click();
});
```

});

Comment: Check the Program Console for any javascript errors

Comment: It shows me "search is not defined" JS is Ok to work IE not chrome.

Comment: And also I found this error in chrome:                                                    
    This page isn’t working

Chrome detected unusual code on this page and blocked it to protect your personal information (for example, passwords, phone numbers, and credit cards).
Try visiting the site's homepage.
ERR_BLOCKED_BY_XSS_AUDITOR

Answer (score 2):

For chrome the variable name is different, so following should help:

```
$('#txtSearch').keypress(function(e){
  var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
  if(key == 13)
     $('#btnSearch').click();
  });
});
```

`e.charCode` is used in Chrome